# How to remove author information in sigconf template (acmart.cls) for double blind conferences?

Tags: author, acmart, sigplanconf

Are there any special settings that will hide author information during the review phase of a double-blind conferences? Are we supposed to omit the author information ourselves?

Sample code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

% Copyright
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}

% DOI
\acmDOI{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

%Conference
%Conference
\acmConference[Conf'2018]{ACM Conf Conference}{March 2018}{City, USA}
\acmYear{2018}
\copyrightyear{2018}

\acmPrice{15.00}

\begin{document}

    \title{Dummy}

    \author{John Doe}
    \affiliation{%
        \institution{Awesome Institute of Technology}
        \state{Country} 
    }
    \email{john.doe@gmail.com}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Dummy abstract
\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```

Is there any better alternative to removing the "John Doe" lines of author information?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 20):

you can add the parameter "anonymous=true" to your document class, so that it becomes:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,anonymous=true]{acmart}
```

or, as suggested in the comments by @gabor-szarnyas, just

```
\documentclass[sigconf,anonymous]{acmart}
```

You can keep it until the review process finishes, and then just replace true with false (or simply remove the "anonymous" parameter)

Comment: `\documentclass[sigconf,anonymous]{acmart}` also works.

Comment: Is there any way to suppress the "anon" from the header of second page onwards?