# How do I remove references to my own papers with natbib in acmart.cls?

Tags: citing, natbib, acmart

I found [this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380228/how-to-remove-author-information-in-sigconf-template-acmart-cls-for-double-bli), which helps with the names in the header, but I now have to hide references to our own previous work interspersed in the text. Is there a special command for that?

Comment: Do you have to remove just the citation call-outs, or both the call-outs and the corresponding entries in the bibliography? And, do please tell us which bibliography style you emplyoy.

Comment: It'll have to be both, as the list of references starts straight after the closing paragraph, so it's not easy to remove. The style is numeric, and you can find the file here https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/blob/master/ACM-Reference-Format.bst Does this help?

Comment: LaTeX and BibTeX don't "know" which `\cite` instructions point to publications (co)authored by you and which ones do not. Hence, the only solution is to (a) remove (or comment out) all `\cite` instrucitons that point to publications you (co)authored and then to rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully update the document.

Comment: I suspected that much, I was hoping there was some special form of the `\cite` command that automatically omits the reference if some options in the document class is on.

Comment: The `natbib` package and the `amsart` document class definitely don't provide such a special form of `\cite`.