# ACM acmart template anonymous mode conditional text

Tags: conditionals, acmart

I'm writing a conference paper using the `acmart` template. As the conference is blind, I've set the anonymous=true option ([How to remove author information in `sigconf` template `(acmart.cls`) for double blind conferences?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387654/62743)) and it works great! Not happy with that, I wondered how to print a block of text if I'm in anonymous mode?

I looked at the acmart.cls file and it defines a boolean key:

```
\define@boolkey+{acmart.cls}[@ACM@]{anonymous}[true]{%
  \if@ACM@anonymous
    \PackageInfo{\@classname}{Using anonymous mode}%
  \else
    \PackageInfo{\@classname}{Not using anonymous mode}%
  \fi}
```

I tried to use this inside my document:

```
  \if@ACM@anonymous
    \textbf{last line should be 901!}
  \fi
```

It is a reminder not to go over 8 pages :-) , but the text is not displayed. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@` has special meaning and can't be used as-is with macros. You need to brace your `@`-enabled commands using a `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother` pair:

```
\makeatletter
\if@ACM@anonymous
   <your conditional text here>
\fi
\makeatother
```

Reference: [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)